# Issues initializing UIWebView inside ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to initialize a `UIWebview` object inside of my `WebViewController`. I'm having a bit of trouble initializing it, and directing it to the URL that is sent to it from the previous `ViewController`.

In the `viewDidLoad` of my `WebViewController`, I attempt to initialize it with the following:

```
    UIWebView *tempWebview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:theFrame];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_itemURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.myWebView = tempWebview;
    [tempWebview loadRequest:urlRequest];
    _myWebView.delegate=self;

    [WebViewController loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

However, this gives me errors stating:
`use of undeclared identifier'theFrame'`, and `no known class method for selector loadRequest`.

Full code is below:

**WebViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *itemURL;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;

@end
```

**WebViewController.m:**

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *tempWebview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:theFrame];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_itemURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.myWebView = tempWebview;
    [tempWebview loadRequest:urlRequest];
    _myWebView.delegate=self;

    [WebViewController loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `theFrame`? Is `_itemURL` being set properly? You're trying to call `loadRequest`, which is an instance method on `UIWebViews`, as a class method on `WebViewController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define that you are going to use the UIWebView Delegate in your .h file as:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

When you already have a webView defined in your Xib file, why are you creating another UIWebView and assigning it to the IBOutlet's webView? You could simply do:

```
  self.myWebView.delegate = self;  //Note that I have set the delegate first before calling LoadRequest

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

  [self.myWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];         

  [self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
```